# Is there a way to create an RMarkdown document from within an R function?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

As part of my data analysis workflow, I want to create a function that takes data as input and returns an Rmarkdown document with the output of a bunch of analyses. I don't understand how to do this very directly, though.

I guess I could create a second r script or .rmd scipt with the code to prepare the html output file and then have the r function write the data to disk with a specific filename to be used in the analysis and then have the function `knitr::spin` or `knitr::knit` the 2nd script into the output file. But is there a more direct way of doing this from within the same script?

Comment: Sure. It's just text, and eg `cat()` and other functions are happy to write to file.

Comment: I believe what you're suggesting would be to have the function write the data to file and write the 2nd script to file, then run the 2nd script to produce the report. Yes?

Comment: You can pass [parameters](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/params-knit.html) to a RMarkdown file when calling `render`.